# Angular pushing to array from selection breaks order

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a material selection drop down that looks like this:

```
<chart-container class="selection-chart" [config]="chartConfig">
        <mat-form-field>
               <mat-label>Selections *</mat-label>
               <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions" name="optionSelection" multiple (selectionChange)="onConfigurationChanged()">
                    <mat-option [disabled]="selectedOptions.length > 2 && !selectedOptions.includes(option)" *ngFor="let option of optionList" [value]="option">{{option.name}}</mat-option>
               </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
<chart-container>
```

It is fairly straightforward, basically the user can select up to 3 options from the list of 10+ options.

When the user selects an option, it gets added to `selectedOptions`. However, I am having an issue with the ordering within `selectedOptions`.

If the user selects the first item on the list as their first selection, no issues are encountered. The simplified array looks like this: `[1]`.

If the user then adds the 5th item on the list, the array looks like this: `[1,5]`.

However, if they then make their third selection as the item 2nd on the list, the order of the array becomes: `[1, 2, 5]`.

ie, the second item gets added to the middle of the array as opposed to what I would prefer:

`[1, 5, 2]` - that is the order the options were selected.

Is there a way I can ensure this?

EDIT:

`onConfigurationChanged` simply looks like this:

```
let dataFetchObservables: Observable<OverviewData[]>[] = [];
if (this.selectedOptions.length > 0) {
            this.updateChartTitles();
        }
```

Comment: Please include `onConfigurationChanged` method

Comment: added now, thanks!

Comment: that does not shows how you populate those options, you'd need to share how you're exactly building that array of options (optionList)

Comment: you have to add it in some non-standard way, if you'll use `array.push(item)` it goes to the end of the array as on example below: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nxtxgb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: @akkonrad: The options are populated by the `ngModel` binding.

Comment: Yes, as MichaelD says, the ngModel binding takes care of adding the options to the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your items with Date property, something like (didn't test it):

Declare the wrapper interface

```
export interface Documented<T> {
  Item: T;  
  Time: Date;
}
```

Map your objects

```
// optionList:YourOptionsType[];
wrappedOptionList:Documented<YourOptionsType>[];
wrappedSelectedOptions:Documented<YourOptionsType>[];

this.YourService.getOptions().subscribe((options:YourOptionsType[])=>{
    this.wrappedOptionList = options.map(op=> { return { Item:op, Time:null } as Documented<YourOptionsType> })
})
```

Handle the event when the option changed

```
optionChanged(opt,event){
  if(event.isUserInput) {
    //console.log(event.source.value, event.source.selected);
    opt.Time = event.source.selected ? new Date() : null;
  }
}
```

Use it in your template. Notice that I have added the `(onSelectionChange)="optionChanged(wrappedOption,$event)"` to `mat-option`.

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="wrappedSelectedOptions" name="optionSelection" multiple (selectionChange)="onConfigurationChanged()">
  <mat-option [disabled]="wrappedSelectedOptions.length > 2 && !wrappedSelectedOptions.includes(wrappedOption)" *ngFor="let wrappedOption of wrappedOptionList" [value]="wrappedOption" (onSelectionChange)="optionChanged(wrappedOption,$event)" >{{wrappedOption?.Item?.name}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Then in your `onConfigurationChanged` method

```
let SortedSelections = this.wrappedSelectedOptions.sort((a: Documented<YourOptionsType>, b: Documented<YourOptionsType>) => { 
  return a.Time.getTime() - b.Time.getTime();
});
```